# How to use regex to unmatch the line if certain word exists on that line?

Tags: regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I have the following regex

```
(?!.*internal).*auditor['’s]*.*(?=report)|(?!.*internal)(?<=report).*auditor['’s]*.*
```

and the following test cases

```
report of auditor
report of external auditor
auditor external report
in auditor report
auditor report
internal report of auditor
report of internal auditor
auditor internal report
```

I want to match if there is `report` before or after `auditor['’s]*` but I do not want to match if the word `internal` presents

with my above regex `internal report of auditor` will be matched.

Here is the desired result

```
report of auditor
report of external auditor
auditor external report
in auditor report
auditor report
```

Here is the [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9sF5HZ/2)

Comment: What  do you mean you don't want to match *the* line. There are *three* lines with "internal" in them.

Comment: Also, is not just that "report" is before or after "auditior", but rather "report" is after "auditor's"  *or* "report" is before "auditor" (without the 's)?

Comment: @ Bohemian♦, 1. I do not want to match those three lines; 2. it is before or after `auditor` with or without `'s`

Comment: OK, so the `'s` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"'s"` suffix to `"auditor"` seems irrelevant, so remove that unnecessary complication.

You requirement can be expressed as:

- contains `"auditor"`
- contains `"report"` (because "before or after something" just means "contains" - the "something" is irrelevant)
- does not contain `"internal"`

Putting that in to regex:

```
^(?!.*\binternal\b)(?=.*\breport\b).*\bauditor\b.*
```

I put word boundaries (`\b`) around the terms, so for example "internalization"  and "reporting" aren't matches.

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/HlHqQUSGJ2DmHT), showing this matching all but the last 3 lines of your sample input.